# Eliminar valores repetidos en consulta Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Me encuentro llenando un Select dinamicamente, desde una table en MySql. El problema es que la query me trae valores repetidos. Lo que quiero es quitar los valores repetidos, para poder mostrarlo en pantalla. Adjunto dejo los códigos.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <?php 
                $query = "SELECT ppu FROM medicion";
                $resultados = mysqli_query($enlace, $query);
            ?>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>PPU</option>
                <?php 

                while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados)) {                      
                    echo "<option value=".$resultado['id'].">".$resultado['ppu']."</option>";
                } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>Normal select</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la cláusula **DISTINCT** de MySQL para seleccionar solo aquellos valores que sean diferentes.

Tu código quedaría algo así:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <?php 
                // aquí añadimos el DISTINCT
                $query = "SELECT DISTINCT ppu FROM medicion";
                $resultados = mysqli_query($enlace, $query);
            ?>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>PPU</option>
                <?php 

                while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados)) {                      
                    echo "<option value=".$resultado['id'].">".$resultado['ppu']."</option>";
                } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>Normal select</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Otra opción sería utilizar **GROUP BY** de MySQL

El código quedaría así:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <?php 
                // aquí añadimos el GROUP BY
                $query = "SELECT ppu FROM medicion GROUP BY ppu";
                $resultados = mysqli_query($enlace, $query);
            ?>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>PPU</option>
                <?php 

                while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados)) {                      
                    echo "<option value=".$resultado['id'].">".$resultado['ppu']."</option>";
                } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>Normal select</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: En cuanto le di enviar a la publicación, fuí a google  encontre el DISTINCT, ahora lo que debo hacer es cada vez que selecciono una me cargue el otro select con unos valores. Podrías ayudarme con eso.

Me imagino que tambien tendría que usar un SELECT

SELECT DISTINCT `periodo` FROM `medicion` WHERE `ppu` = PPU